# django, count number of posts from the 'name' of the user

Tags: django, django-filter

**I want to make a filter that takes the users name and returns the number of posts they have made.**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<User: jack>, <User: lenovo>]>
```

I can see my users. And then I was thinking within the html something like this:

```
<p>jack has written {% jack|total_posts %} posts so far. lenovo has written {% lenovo|total_posts %} </p>
```

I have blog_tags.py file for my filters, and I have some simple tags already working, but bit confused by the volume of available information.

I have this so far:

```
@register.filter
def total_posts(user=jack):
    return #expression to count jacks posts.
```

but stuck on the return expression. Any suggestions/corrections would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is `jack` in `...(user=jack)`? You are also confusing user objects with usernames. Are you planning to hard code the usernames into html in advance?

Comment: I was hardcoding for simplicity in this instance. I also see exactly what you are saying about confusing user objects and usernames, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use names to access data. Also don't repeat the same code again. Let's assume you have a Post model that links to your User model with a ForeignKey:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.User)
    # ... more fields ...
```

Get all the users in your .py file.

```
from django.db.models import Count    
user_posts = User.objects.annotate(total_posts = Count('post'))
```

Then in your template file do the following.

```
{% for user in user_posts %}

<p>{{user.first_name}} has written {% user.total_posts %} posts so far <p>

{% endfor %}
```

This will print out all the users with their posts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the username as a string: 'jack'.  Let's assume you have a `Post` model that links to your `User` model with a `ForeignKey`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.User)
    # ... more fields ...
```

We can ask Django to look for any posts that have a `User` object with the passed-in username:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__username=user)
```

And we can then count them using the queryset `count()` method:

```
post_count = posts.count()
```

That is the value that you'd want to return from your template filter.